# Trying to install tenserflow on jupypter notebook returns "subprocess-exited-with-error"

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I ran the input: "!pip install tensorflow tensorflow-gpu opencv-python matplotlib" and it returned the following error:

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

The error has to do with the subprocess and not pip, which is updated to the latest version. In the output, "python_version>"3.7" with an arrow pointing at the greater than sign comes up twice.

I think the error has to do with the version of python being used. I have python 3.11 installed, which TenserFlow supports. I asked this question to ChatGPT and it told me I should put in "PYTHON_VERSION="python_version<3.7"" into the input, but it didn't change anything.

Edit:The problem was that I was trying to install tensorflow-gpu, which is now part of tensorflow. I just got rid of that part of the command and it worked.

Comment: This question is unanswerable without knowing what error was printed above the section saying that a subprocess exited.